# Can solr 3.6 support Chinese language?

Tags: solr, localization, full-text-search

I found it support lot of languages but Chinese.

**Update**
I can use Luke search my data, please see the screenshot
[image]
Tried this:
Add

```
    <fieldType name="text_chinese" class="solr.TextField">
         <analyzer type="index">
        <tokenizer class="solr.CJKTokenizerFactory"/>
        </analyzer>
    </fieldType>
```

to schema.xml, also tried

```
   <fieldType name="text_chinese" class="solr.TextField">
      <analyzer class="org.apache.lucene.analysis.cn.ChineseAnalyzer"/>
   </fieldType>
```

and

```
 <fieldType name="text_general" class="solr.TextField" positionIncrementGap="100">
  <analyzer type="index">
    <tokenizer class="solr.CJKTokenizerFactory"/>
    <filter class="solr.StopFilterFactory" ignoreCase="true" words="stopwords.txt" enablePositionIncrements="true" />
    <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
  </analyzer>
  <analyzer type="query">
    <tokenizer class="solr.StandardTokenizerFactory"/>
    <filter class="solr.StopFilterFactory" ignoreCase="true" words="stopwords.txt" enablePositionIncrements="true" />
    <filter class="solr.SynonymFilterFactory" synonyms="synonyms.txt" ignoreCase="true" expand="true"/>
    <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
  </analyzer>
</fieldType>
```

But none of this work.
I am wondering what exactly the format of "`<fieldType name=`", it's text_chinese or text_cn or text_zh_cn? but I have tried all this format.

By the way, I can search my document by using engnlish attribute. And I can't search by enter
"name:something" in my web browser UI, I got exception:

```
org.springframework.dao.InvalidDataAccessApiUsageException: Bad Request

Bad Request

request: http://localhost:8180/solr/select?q=name:*name:something* or description:*name:something* or type:*name:something* or mac_address:*name:something* or uri:*name:something* or attrs:*name:something*&start=0&rows=0&wt=javabin&version=2; nested exception is org.apache.solr.common.SolrException: Bad Request

Bad Request

request: http://localhost:8180/solr/select?q=name:*name:something* or description:*name:something* or type:*name:something* or mac_address:*name:something* or uri:*name:something* or attrs:*name:something*&start=0&rows=0&wt=javabin&version=2
    at org.springframework.data.solr.core.SolrExceptionTranslator.translateExceptionIfPossible(SolrExceptionTranslator.java:58)
    at org.springframework.data.solr.core.SolrTemplate.execute(SolrTemplate.java:106)
    at org.springframework.data.solr.core.SolrTemplate.count(SolrTemplate.java:126)
    at org.springframework.data.solr.repository.query.AbstractSolrQuery$CollectionExecution.count(AbstractSolrQuery.java:92)
    at org.springframework.data.solr.repository.query.AbstractSolrQuery$CollectionExecution.execute(AbstractSolrQuery.java:87)
    at org.springframework.data.solr.repository.query.AbstractSolrQuery.execute(AbstractSolrQuery.java:52)
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport$QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.invoke(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:313)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:172)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:202)
```

Is this a spring data solr bug?

Comment: What did you refer to get the list of supported languages? I'm guessing you want to be able to search Chinese text - is there anything beyond this that you want to use Solr for?

Comment: Yes, I just want Chinese text can be indexed and searchable.

Comment: Hi @Tom, can you post details on how you create your query? the query string of the request above looks a little strange `code`q=name:*name:something*...`code`

Comment: Hi Strobl, I use spring data solr. I will check the query string,thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The [SmartChineseAnalyzer](http://lucene.apache.org/core/4_0_0/analyzers-smartcn/org/apache/lucene/analysis/cn/smart/SmartChineseAnalyzer.html) seems to do a the typical analyzer implementation for indexing chinese text.

Further tools are available in the [smartcn API](http://lucene.apache.org/core/4_0_0/analyzers-smartcn/overview-summary.html), and the [CJKTokenizer](http://lucene.apache.org/core/4_0_0/analyzers-common/org/apache/lucene/analysis/cjk/CJKTokenizer.html) is a good tokenizer for Chinese (as well as Japanese and Korean, thus the name).

Comment: I use solr,not lucene directly,actually, I also didn't use solr directly, I am using spring data solr, so I didn't have any chance to use api in my code. Or can you provide me how to config  SmartChineseAnalyzer and CJKTokenizer in solr?

Comment: You can use the Solr CJKTokenizerFactory simply as `<tokenizer class="solr.CJKTokenizerFactory"/>`, or set it to use the Simplified chinese analyzer like: `<analyzer class="org.apache.lucene.analysis.cn.smart.SmartChineseAnalyzer"/>`.

Comment: Added  `<fieldType name="text_cn" class="solr.TextField">
  <analyzer class="org.apache.lucene.analysis.cn.smart.SmartChineseAnalyzer"/>
    </fieldType>` to schema.xml,copy lucene-smartcn-3.5.0.jar and solr-analysis-extras-3.5.0.jar to SolrApp\lib, index my data and search,but get nothing.

Comment: You may need to add the jar for that analyzer manually to your Solr war.  Have you done this?  The `CJKTokenizerFactory` should work out of the box.  Also, you might benefit from looking at the contents of your index.  [Luke](http://www.getopt.org/luke/) is a good tool for this.

Comment: Hi,thanks for you help, please see my updated post,It described what I have done.

Comment: SmartChinese only works for Simplified Chinese. To apply it to Traditional Chinese, one has to translate the dictionary to traditional-chinese-semantic-equivalent vocabularies.

Comment: As far as my experience, CJK is most acceptable one for our users.

Comment: Another possible workaround for Chinese is to use "shingle", i.e. phrase-gram. However, newer version of Solr is recommended since there's a bug on shingle in earlier version.

Answer (score 0):

```
<fieldType name="wc_text" class="solr.TextField" positionIncrementGap="100">
  <analyzer type="index">
    <tokenizer class="solr.ChineseTokenizerFactory"/>
    <filter class="solr.StopFilterFactory" ignoreCase="true" words="stopwords.txt" enablePositionIncrements="true" />
    <filter class="solr.WordDelimiterFilterFactory" generateWordParts="1" generateNumberParts="1" catenateWords="1" catenateNumbers="1" catenateAll="0" splitOnCaseChange="0" preserveOriginal="1"/>
    <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>

    <filter class="solr.RemoveDuplicatesTokenFilterFactory"/>
  </analyzer>
  <analyzer type="query">
    <tokenizer class="solr.ChineseTokenizerFactory"/>
    <filter class="solr.StopFilterFactory" ignoreCase="true" words="stopwords.txt" enablePositionIncrements="true" />
    <filter class="solr.WordDelimiterFilterFactory" generateWordParts="1" generateNumberParts="1" catenateWords="0" catenateNumbers="0" catenateAll="0" splitOnCaseChange="0" preserveOriginal="1"/>
    <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
    <filter class="solr.RemoveDuplicatesTokenFilterFactory"/>
  </analyzer>
</fieldType
```

Use the above filter factory for chinese characeters and use the  UTF-8 encoding in the application side.